# Continuous Proper functions

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that a continuous proper function maps closed sets to closed sets.

So far I have this: Let $A$ be closed we want to show that $f(A)$ is closed. Let $y$ be a limit point of $\bar{f(A)}.$ with $y_n$ converging to $y$. We need to show y in $f(A)$. Put $y_n=f(x_n)$. So $x_n$ is a sequence in $A$ with $x_n \rightarrow x$. Note that $x\in A$ since $A$ is closed.

Comment: What is a 'proper' function?

Comment: We have $\arctan \mathbb{R} = (-1,1)$, so proper must mean more than well defined.

Comment: It's false in that case ($e^x : \mathbb R \to (0,\infty)$). Proper usually means "$K$ compact implies $f^{-1}(K)$ is compact"

Comment: f is proper  iff the inverse image of any compact set is compact @copper.hat. My function is from $R_n \rightarrow R_n$

Comment: @Tim And all involved spaces are locally compact Hausdorff spaces?

Comment: We didn't discuss locally compact Hausdorff spaces in my class. I have no idea what that is @DanielFischer

Comment: If $f_n \to f$ with $f_n \in f(A)$ then $\{f_n\} \cup \{f\}$ is compact.

Comment: I see where you are going with that I can say that $\{y_n\} \cup \{y\}$ is compact to its inverse image is compact. @copper.hat

Comment: If $f(a_n) \to L$, then this means that $a_n$ lie in some compact set, hence have an accumulation point $a$ and we must have $f(a) = L$ by continuity.

Comment: so we get $y \in f(A)$ because f is continuous and well definded

Answer (score 0):

For $x_n \to x$ you need the properness!

So assume for ease that $f: X \to Y$ is proper and continuous and let $C$ be closed in $X$ and let $y \in \overline{f[C]}$. Following your proof, we pick $y_n \in f[C]$ such that $y_n \to y$. Then pick $x_n \in C$ such that $f(x_n) = y_n$ for all $n$.

Now note that $S = \{y_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{y\}$ is compact (clear from the definition as any open set covering $y$ already covers all but finitely many $y_n$, by convergence, etc.). So $f^{-1}[S]$ is compact and all $x_n \in f^{-1}[S]$ so there is a convergent subsequence $x_{n_k}$ and some $x \in f^{-1}[S]$ such that $x_{n_k} \to x\, (k \to \infty)$. But then continuity kicks in and we conclude that $y_{n_k}= f(x_{n_k}) \to f(x)$ as $k \to \infty$. But already $y_{n_k} \to y$ as all subsequences of a convergent sequence converge to the same limit. As in metric spaces limits are unique, we get $f(x) = y$.

Now note that all $x_n \in C$ which implies that $x \in C$ as well, as $C$ is closed (here we finally use it). So $y = f(x) \in f[C]$ and so $f[C]$ is closed in $Y$.